# Crontab woes --- help me figure out why it's not running

Tags: php, cron

I'm having troubles creating a crontab that executes a series of php scripts when I specify it. From what I can tell the cron doesn't even run...
Also if someone knows a method to allow me to run multiple php scripts at once that'd be great!

```
##data upload stream 1
30 09,11,13,15,17,19,21,23 * * 1-5 /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=ic -a=/data/cp.csv && /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=ic -g=/data/g.csv
#
##data upload stream 2
0 22 * * 1-5 /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=ss -d=/data/d.csv && (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=ss -c=/data/c_east.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=ss -c=/data/c_central.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=ss -c=/data/c_west.csv) && (php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_701.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_702.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_703.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_704.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_705.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_706.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_707.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_708.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_709.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_710.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_713.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_751.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_752.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_753.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_754.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_755.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_756.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_757.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_758.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_759.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_760.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_761.csv; php pushCSV.php --system=dw -u=/data/u_762.csv)
##
##data upload stream 3
0 22 6 1 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 6 2 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
#0 22 6 3 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 4 4 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 6 5 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 5 6 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 4 7 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 6 8 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 5 9 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 4 10 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 6 11 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
0 22 5 12 * (/php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_704; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_705.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_706.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_707.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_708.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_709.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_710.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_713.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_751.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_752.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_753.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_754.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_755.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_756.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_757.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_758.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_759.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_760.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_761.csv; /php_scripts/php pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_762.csv)
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Josh

Comment: 1st: does the script show any output when started from command line? 2nd: did you try to add a ">/tmp/test.txt" to see if it shows any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you put the path to the php scripts in front of the php binary. It should look like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /php_scripts/pushCSV.php
```

I would put those commands into a bash script and call the bash script from cron:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php /php_scripts/pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_701.csv 
/usr/bin/php /php_scripts/pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_702.csv 
/usr/bin/php /php_scripts/pushCSV.php --system=dw -r=/data/ar_703.csv 
# --- etc ---
```